# is this possible to develop Call Blocker app in Windows Phone 8.0/8.1?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-mobile, phone-call

I need to develop call blocker app in Windows Phone, I just heard that due to restriction of library, this is not possible in Windows Phone. Am I Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You are right.

Call and SMS api is only available for OEM(Original equipment manufacturer) because of user privacy. So you can not use it.